# Обновление содержимого чата с помощью setInterval

Tags: jquery

Делаю чат, сообщения выводятся все хорошо, но чтобы выводились новые сообщения нужно обновлять страницу. Знаю про `setInterval`, но не знаю как им воспользоваться. Можете подсказать, как мне сделать обновление чата без перезагрузки страницы.

Если я правильно понимаю, то нужно повторять этот кусок кода:

```
var zapros = {
url: "main.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
  action:"send_message",
  message: msg,
  userID: userID
},
success: function(data){
  //alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
} $.ajax(zapros);}
```

Comment: `setInterval(function () { /* тут запрос */ }, 10000 /* 10 сек */)`

Comment: А если этот запрос у меня уже в функции send ? Как мне вытянуть его от туда ) Или setInterval можно впихнуть туда ? 
function send(){
.....
var zapros = {
    url: "main.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action:"send_message",
      message: msg,
      userID: userID
    },
    success: function(data){
      //alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
    }
  };
  $.ajax(zapros);
  }

Comment: Если в `send` входит отправка запроса и обработка результата, то можно просто `setInterval(send, 10000 /* 10 сек */)`

Comment: Я пытался так сделать , но помимо запроса там есть добавление сообщения ( Div) И получается когда я делаю setInterval(send,1000 ) У меня появляются пустые сообщения в бд )